Mint new position not working for all existing pairs
I am using uniswap v3 mintNewPosition to mint new liquidity position .So i called mintNewPosition() function mentioned in https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/providing-liquidity/mint-a-position . The issue is this function works correctly on only some specific pairs with specific fee like DAI/USDC with pool fee 0.01 and USDC/USDT with pool fee 0.01 . i cant mintNewPosition with other pairs . I am using ethereum forknet . What is the reason for which i can only mintNewPostion with some specific pairs but cant mintNewPosition with other pairs(existing pool pairs) ?
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers, network } from "hardhat";

describe("LiquidityManager", function () {
  let liquidityManager;
  let token0Contract;
  let token1Contract;
  let token0Decimal;
  let token1Decimal
  let user;
  let token0Amount;
  let token1Amount;
  let tokenId;

  // let token0Address = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"; // WETH
  // let token1Address = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"; // USDT

  let token0Address = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";  // DAI
  let token1Address = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";  // USDC

  // let token0Address = "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48";  // USDC
  // let token1Address = "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7";  // USDT

  // let token0Address = "0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984";  // UNI
  // let token1Address = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2";  // WETH

  token0Decimal = 18;
  token1Decimal = 6;


  beforeEach(async function () {
    user = await ethers.getSigners();
    const LiquidityManager = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "LiquidityManager"
    );
    liquidityManager = await LiquidityManager.deploy();
    await liquidityManager.deployed();
    console.log("Pass 1");
    token0Contract = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", token0Address);
    token1Contract = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", token1Address);
    console.log("Pass 2");
    token0Amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1",token0Decimal);
    token1Amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", token1Decimal);
    console.log("Pass 3");
    await token0Contract.connect(user[0]).approve(liquidityManager.address, ethers.constants.MaxUint256);
    console.log("Pass 4");
    await token1Contract.connect(user[0]).approve(liquidityManager.address, ethers.constants.MaxUint256);
    console.log("Pass 5");
    await token0Contract.connect(user[0]).transfer(liquidityManager.address, token0Amount);
    console.log("Pass 6");
    await token1Contract.connect(user[0]).transfer(liquidityManager.address, token1Amount);
    console.log("Pass 7");
  });
  
  it("mintNewPosition", async function () {
    console.log("mintNewPosition working");
    const amount0ToMint = token0Amount;
    const amount1ToMint = token1Amount;
    console.log("Pass 9 ",amount0ToMint,amount1ToMint);
    const tx = await liquidityManager.mintNewPosition(token0Address,token1Address,amount0ToMint,amount1ToMint,100,-887272,887272);
    console.log("Pass 10 ");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    // console.log("Pass 11",receipt);
    const events = receipt.events?.filter((x) => x.event == "PositionMinted");
    // console.log("Pass 12 ",events);
    if (events !== undefined && events.length > 0) {
      tokenId = events[0].args["tokenId"].toString();
      console.log(tokenId);
    }
  });
});



The fee tier determines the pool being swapped on, what are the pool reserves at the addresses generated on the other fee tiers? As you say that function will not initialize a pool where one does not yet exist. .. Should also test with amountOutMins set to 0, since for dai/usdc for example .3% and 1% fee tier pool have low liquidity, $400 and $4 and maybe some issue with specific amounts.
